# Exiting for-loop in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have at least 2 problems with the code but I will start with this one.

The following code does not seem to work correctly:

```
cout<<"Vill du mata in en post till? (ja/nej)"<<endl; //I'm asking if the user wants to run the for-loop one more time or brake with ja(yes) or nej(no).
cin>>svar;

if (svar == ja)
{
        return 0;      
}
```

The problem is that if the user answers no it does **not** brake but instead runs trough the for-loop without "running" or "executing" the `cin>>` lines.

I did some troubleshooting and found that if I change `if (svar == ja)` to `if (svar != nej)` it brakes the for-loop, but the problem is it does so even if I put in ja(yes) or anything else...

Heres is the full code, thank you for any help you can provide:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct telefonbok 
{
    string namn;
    string nummer;           
};

int main()
{
   int ja, nej;
   telefonbok post[10];
   bool svar; //behövs för frågan om man vill fortsätta.

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
     cout<<"Lagg till en post i telefonboken."<<endl;
     cout<<"Ange personens namn: "<<endl;
     cin>>post[i].namn;
     cout<<"Ange personens nummer :"<<endl;
     cin>>post[i].nummer;
     cout<<"Vill du mata in en post till? (ja/nej)"<<endl;
     cin>>svar;

     if (svar == ja) //stoppar slingan om man svarar nej
     {
         return 0;      
     }

}

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ja needs to be a string and you need to use a string comparison function to check for equality.

Comment: Any reason why ja is uninitialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Svar should be a string (since you are expecting the user to enter a string "ja" or "nej", and not an integer which the code expects), and you should probably check for `"nej"` instead of `"ja"` considering the question you ask. If you only want to exit the loop and not the function use `break`:

```
// ...
string svar = "";

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    // ...
    cout<<"Vill du mata in en post till? (ja/nej)"<<endl;
    cin >> svar;

    if (svar == "nej")
    {
        return 0;
        // If you only want to exit the loop and not the function you can use:
        // break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable `ja` and `nej` are not initialized. Comparing `svar` to them is futile.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it's immediately clear that you are attempting to compare a string to an uninitialized int called `ja`. If you want to compare svar to something that will return a meaningful value, you will want to compare a string to a string, i.e.

`if (svar == "ja")` instead of `if (svar == ja)`.

I can't see anywhere else in the code where the ints "ja" and "nej" are used. What is their purpose?

Comment: His code states: `bool svar; //behövs för frågan om man vill fortsätta.`